# Apache kylin and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, apache, data-warehouse, kylin

I’m a student and i’m working on my last year project, the project is about Data warhousing, BI, etc...
So Im asked to work with Apache Kylin 
I did some researchs about it, learned some
And I looked for if it is possible to use a PostgreSQL as Data warehouse and make it communicate with Apache Kylin to build cubes

But found nothing...

So would you please answer to my following question:

Is it possible to make the apache kylin communicate with a postgreSQL DWH?

And if there is some hidden documentations about it would you please share it?

Time is running guys and i really appreciate your answers and guides

Thanks in advance.
Khalil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable. Kylin provides data source adapter for JDBC data sources. PostgreSQL could be one of the data source adapters. MySQL is supported by default. You could check this link to learn more: http://kylin.apache.org/development/datasource_sdk.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will take a look to that !

Comment: And here is a brief blog introducing this SDK: https://kylin.apache.org/blog/2019/01/16/introduce-data-source-sdk-v2.6.0/

On the latest Kylin meetup, Dong Li gave a talk on this topic, here is the presentation: https://www.slidestalk.com/s/apache_kylin_data_source_sdk (although it is in Chinese, most of content is readable I think)

Comment: Thank you very much that was helpful :)